# How get popup alert if the form send success

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The form:

```
<form name="htmlform" action="index.html" method="post"/>
<input type="text" id="companyname" name="companyname"/>
<span id='htmlform_companyname_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<input type="contact" id="contactperson" name="contactperson"/>
<span id='htmlform_contactperson_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Validation:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

// <![CDATA[

var frmvalidator= new Validator("htmlform");
frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

frmvalidator.addValidation("companyname","req","Please provide company name");  
frmvalidator.addValidation("contactperson","req","Who is the contact person?");
// ]]>
</script>
```

How can I get a pop window if the form submitted successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to redirect the user to page that has the popup screen for you
the case is:

- if user submit the form

  - 1.1.when not valid then stay in the same page
  - 1.2.when is valid then (you can do this) go to another page / (or this) stay on the same page

you need to set variable when it successful submitted and then check it later on your view